# How to convert an emoji image to Unicode in JavaScript, or reflect a custom emoji for a given Unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode, sprite, emoji

I'm trying to understand how to implement custom emojis for user input and I can't seem to get a handle on it.

I see that sites like Facebook initially show a list of small **.png** emoji images, then, once you click the image, it converts it to a Unicode character.

Also, I've been digging through custom emoji packages that use sprite images.

**I can't find any material** that explains how to utilize a sprite, or a single image, then convert this to Unicode on the fly to be displayed later.

If you can't convert images to Unicode on the fly, how is it that different sites reflect their own custom version of an emoji with a given Unicode character?

Comment: Better will be attaching some `id` to the emogi `<img>` tag, have some mapping for `ID` and Unicode characters, the define some function where you can change the content from image to Unicode character.

Comment: You cannot convert an image to a unicode. This is a mapping, a list provided like here: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html and depends on the provider of the images

Comment: @Joschi Okay, so if it's _always_ just converted to its unicode representation, and the unicode interpreter is on your local operating system, how is it that different sites (ie facebook and twitter) have different versions of particular emojis?

Comment: @silencedogood The different emojis you see are images, not unicode. Take a closer look at the link I provided.
They do this to make sure they look all the same on every device, browser. They have no influence on how they will be displayed - so they use images that will look everywhere the same.

Comment: @Joschi I vaguely understand. So a reference to some image is stored, and this referenced image is then displayed by calling the reference properties. Someone mentioned openmoji as an answer, could you post a working example that references an `openmoji` reference image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, there are two methods for adding emoji functionality to user inputs:

1. **Unicode characters**, which relies on a custom font imported by the developer ***OR*** the browser vendors default font, to determine which version of a particular emoji is used. You simply type in the unicode string and the browser inserts a given emoji based on the font. [Check out unicode emojis here.](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) and also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875299/how-to-use-an-emoji-font-on-a-website) explains more about unicode usage for emojis.
2. **The insertion of images into a rich text editor (RTE).** This technique relies on having single emoji images (typically .png) or [sprite sheets](https://axelpale.github.io/openmoji-sprites/) that the developer can use with the RTE. [This article](https://medium.com/making-faces-and-other-emoji/emoji-on-the-web-537c5769dffa) is a great place to start.

- The first method can be harder to customize the emoji unless you're into making custom fonts. RTE plugins like [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) are a simple and quick way to tinker with unicode emojis.
- The second method becomes a bit more complex, and is used by some of the big players like Facebook and Twitter. As with most things coding, with complexity comes flexibility. This method involves programmatically transposing some plain-text flag such as `:smile:` into an html element like `<img src='smile.png' />`. It creates a text area by utilizing the `contenteditable div` tag. Inside this div, the content is edited programmatically in order to add or remove emoji images, bold/italic letters, etc...

In order to better understand how the second method works, I created [react-ez-emoji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ez-emoji), which is a lightweight, emoji-enabled `contenteditable div` that allows you to use any emoji image file you'd like. It would be a good start for anyone looking to study the topic, but I don't recommend it for production.

[This article](https://medium.com/making-faces-and-other-emoji/emoji-on-the-web-537c5769dffa) does a good job explaining the limitations of Unicode emojis, and why the second option is more customizable and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point to the OpenMoji Project for Inquiry:
https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji

In the data folder you will see neat look up files you can utilize. Basically they save pngs with the name of the choresponding unicode character in their font, more advanced info is in the json:

```
{
    "emoji": "",
    "hexcode": "1F600",
    "group": "smileys-emotion",
    "subgroups": "face-smiling",
    "annotation": "grinning face",
    "tags": "face, grin",
    "openmoji_tags": "smile, happy",
    "openmoji_author": "Emily Jäger",
    "openmoji_date": "2018-04-18",
    "skintone": "",
    "skintone_combination": "",
    "skintone_base_emoji": "",
    "skintone_base_hexcode": "",
    "unicode": 1,
    "order": 1
}
```

Edit: Sorry, I thought you were interested in how to build lookup table with pngs. My Solution for the problem of adding emoji-fonts to webpage would have been to add a font, but thats not working:
[How to use an emoji font on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875299/how-to-use-an-emoji-font-on-a-website)

I dont think there is a "proper" solution to this problem currently.

Edit2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "OpenMoji Black";
            src: url(OpenMoji-Black.ttf) format("truetype");
        }
        .openmoji { 
            font-family: "OpenMoji Black", fantasy;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="openmoji">
        <span>Hello World &#x1F605;  &#x1F607;</span>
    </body>
</head>
```

Works sweet with https://github.com/hfg-gmuend/openmoji/blob/master/font/OpenMoji-Black.ttf on Chrome, Firefox and even IE.

Comment: Could you give a working example of how these data would be used in order to display this emoji image in place of the native unicode version?

Comment: Think i had problem with the fiddle, locally it worked

Comment: +1 for at least giving me something to tinker with. However, I'm getting the same emoji with or without the `.openmoji` class applied.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have cross site scripting issues loading the font?

Comment: I did, but I went ahead and downloaded it locally to avoid that issue. The font seems to be loading fine, just not reflecting anything different. It's the same sweat-drop emoji with or without it.

Comment: Alright I got it working with [NotoColorEmoji.ttf](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/master/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf) not sure why my browser doesn't like `OpenMoji Black`  I'd still like to see a good write-up on how to utilize sprite images for this purpose. Either way, this got me going so thanks!

Comment: It is still unclear to me what the problem is, as you can use the json file to create a dictionary. Maybe i can get u started with this link to custum textarea tools: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/custom-tools - checkout where they input a horizontal rule <hr> tag. u can do the same and input unicode on a click.