# How are emojis rendered?

Tags: fonts, font-face, emoji, typography

From what I understand, a font, or font-family, may not have all the glyphs defined for every Unicode character. Whenever I have an emoji character, what is the font-family in effect?

For example, if I have:

```html
<p style="font-family:Arial">&#x1f354; Hamburger</p>
```

from which typeface is the hamburger emoji taken?

The reason I am asking is, on my desktop Chrome, emojis are relatively plain and ugly, whereas on my Android Chrome, the same emojis have lots more details and colors. As a web page creator, can I control or select what "fonts" are used to render emojis in a client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an emoji font on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875299/how-to-use-an-emoji-font-on-a-website)

Comment: I think that was refering to a different problem when emojis still could not be rendered directly from Unicode characters. I remember in 2016, to show emojis on a web page I had to use a giant png sheet of all the emojis and then using CSS to offset to display a specific character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the app or site/service, emoji might be displayed using

- bitmap image files, like .pngs
- SVG files
- colour fonts

Colour fonts are commonly used because emoji are represented as text, and a font is the most direct way of displaying text.

If you tell a browser to display text using Arial but the text contains emoji characters, then those characters are not supported by the Arial font and the browser will select a different font. There are far more characters defined in Unicode than a single font like Arial can support, and browsers will have font fallback logic to select from among a number of different fonts depending on the characters to be displayed. As for which font a browser would use as a fallback for emoji, that might depend on the browser, but also on the host OS environment: apps typically use fonts included in the host OS for fallback, but could also bundle their own fonts.

Windows provides Segoe UI Emoji as an emoji font; Apple's OSes provide the Apple Color Emoji font; Google provides Noto Color Emoji.

There are different colour font formats, and current versions of the above emoji fonts each use a different format. You can use [this site](https://pixelambacht.nl/chromacheck/) with different browsers to see which of the colour formats is supported.

If you want to control what fonts are used to display emojis, then don't simply specific a single family like Arial that doesn't support any emoji. Otherwise, you're leaving it up to the browser and host environment. Find an emoji font you like and get a license to use it as a web font; then get it served up as a web font and referenced appropriately in your site using @font-face; and then add that web font into your font-family chain.

Comment: In the old days, operating systems have a font table and simply look up for each (7/8-bit) character on how to render. With emojis, does it mean now OS'es need different look up and rendering methods for different blocks of the Unicode codepoint space? Wouldn't that mean hardcoding and catching up with every version of Unicode?

Comment: OSes definitely use multiple fonts to display text. The OS designers can control what strings they display in the user interface, but they can't predict what Unicode characters might be in user content. For example, you could name a file with any Unicode character, or receive files from others with names using any Unicode characters. So, the OS vendor needs to allow that and provide fonts to cover as much of Unicode as they can.  [cont'd...]

Comment: Google's Noto fonts are intended for just that purpose (the name "Noto" means "no tofu", which basically means 'be able to display any Unicode character'. And there are over 150 fonts that make up the Noto set. Windows has a number of fonts for the same purpose, though Microsoft combines multiple scripts together into the same fonts so there are fewer separate fonts used than with Noto. To some extent that involves hardcoded lists of fonts, though with a new Unicode version it may be possible to add the new characters to existing fonts, so that the list of fonts doesn't necessarily grow.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer noto color emoji as a emoji font, but the emojis is normally taken from the browser. You can choose the emoji font whatever you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).